# neo4j : LIMIT and ORDER BY in COLLECT

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

Consider this cypher query

```
MATCH (a : User)-[c : Commented]->(b) RETURN DISTINCT a.username AS
username, b.postId AS postId, COLLECT({commentBody : c.comments,
commentedOn : c.time})[0..5] AS commentData LIMIT 20;
```

query returns me 'c' starting from 1st and limits it to 5. How can I fetch last five 'c' and then order them by commentedOn. Note** count of number of relations between 'a' and 'c' is not known, could be 1 could be 1000.

What I am trying to achieve is, return up to 20 'a' nodes with last to last-5 related relations 'c' for that path. 
for eg. your instagram home page could have 20 posts and each one of them may have many comments under one post collection, right? I am able to achieve till here, I can collect first 5 relations 'c', my question here is how do I collect last 5 relations 'c' given I have to match 20 'a' nodes.

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting the 20 users? Just any 20 users that have commented on any post, and with those 20 users, get the last 5 comments from each of them on any post?

Comment: @InverseFalcon yup

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to fetch the last five comments - i.e. sort them by their timestamp (descending) and take the top 5. Use [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-with) to chain queries together, for example:

```
MATCH (a : User)-[c : Commented]->(b)
WITH DISTINCT
  a.username AS username,
  b.postId AS postId,
  c.comments AS commentBody,
  c.time AS commentedOn
ORDER BY commentedOn DESC
LIMIT 5
RETURN
   username, collect({postId : postId, commentBody : commentBody, commentedOn : commentedOn}) AS commentData
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: that would put a limit to the entire match result i-e if I want to get comments of 20 users, and each one could have n comments as relations, then it fails. it will give me 20 results which would be a combination of users + comments. For eg. if one user has commented 30 times, this would send me one user and 19 of his comments. What i intent to do is fetch 20 users and max 5 comments from each.

Comment: @RishikRohan okay, I understand it a bit more now. Can you please update your question in the post? What is still unclear for me though - which 20 users would you like to fetch?

Comment: updated the problem statement, let me know If it needs more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of WITH so you can use the first part of your query to match on 20 users, then with those users, collect the last 5 comments of each.

Something like this should work or at least get you lose

```
MATCH (a : User)
// only interested in users that have commented
WHERE (a)-[:Commented]->()
WITH a LIMIT 20
// for those 20 users, get all their comments
MATCH (a)-[c : Commented]->(b)
// order results by time so we collect comments in order later
WITH a, c, b
ORDER BY c.time DESC
// return results, getting only the slice of 5 collected comments for each user
RETURN a.username AS username, COLLECT({commentBody : c.comments, commentedOn : c.time, postId : b.postId})[0..5] AS commentData
```